# sections in table view

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a table view with 2 prototype cells , and 2 custom classes for them .
In first cell I have an image view and in the second cell I have a label . 
This is my code and the image is result : 
I want it to be like this : image cell - label cell - image cell - label cell

```
 var categories = ["first ","second", "third", "forth"]
var banners = ["close-envelope","chat"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0{
        return banners.count
    }else{
        return categories.count
    }
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let bannerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bannerCell", for: indexPath) as! bannerCell
    let catCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoryCell", for: indexPath) as! categoryCell

    if indexPath.section == 0{
        bannerCell.banner.image = UIImage(named: banners[indexPath.row])
        return bannerCell
    }else{
        catCell.lbl.text = categories[indexPath.row]
        catCell.btn.setTitle(categories[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        return catCell
    }
}


@IBOutlet weak var tableview:UITableView!
```

**Output of the code :**

[image]

Comment: @Sh_Khan sry I added

Comment: @Sh_Khan see the picture please , I don't want it , I want it to show image cell - label cell - image cell . but as you can see in the picture it is image cell - image cell - label cell

Comment: @Sh_Khan if I dont need 2 section how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table view implementation contains two sections, the first one *only* has `bannerCell` cells which show an image and the second *only* has `categoryCell` cells which show a label.

Sections are always rendered one after the other, so if you want " image cell - label cell - image cell" you will need to return the correct cell from `tableView: cellForRowAt:`. You probably should only have one section and calculate the cell type and content based on the index's row.

Comment: oh yes , and then it will be the code with one section : `if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
  // image
}
else {
  // label
}`

Comment: @ZahraAsqarzade exactly, or (as was shown in another answer which unfortunately seems to have been deleted) you could also use a data model which better suits your requirements than two string arrays. E.g. an `enum` with two cases `banner` and `category`; having a single array of this would be more flexible than the two separate string arrays. But, of course, if the current solution work for you, that's fine as well :)